# How to get a filter on collection_set Query on a ReferenceProperty'ed attribute to work?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use the Query collection_set from the Referenced Entity to filter and fetch as follows :

```
class Author (db.Model)
   name = db.StringProperty()

class Book (db.Model)
   author = db.ReferenceProperty (collection_name="books", indexed=True)
   name = db.StringProperty()

author = Author.get (author_key)
q = author.books
q.filter ("name =", "BOOK_NAME")
books = q.fetch(5)
```

I am not getting this to return the book. And the following works :

```
author = Author.get (author_key)
q = Book.all()
q.filter ("author =", author.key())
q.filter ("name =", "BOOK_NAME")
books = q.fetch(5)
```

So is the former supposed to work ?

Also, what is the recommend best practice - use authors collection_set or use a filter with author.key() ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you want `objects.filter(field="value")`  not `objects.filter("field=",some_value)`

Comment: Is 'objects' in this case not a db.Query class instance ? In other cases this 'q.filter ("field =", value)' works : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass (Thanks)